# NHibernate QueryOver Select only needed model

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I've encountered a little problem selecting only the needed model in QueryOver.
Here my scenario

```
 var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<ModelA>(() => Ma)
                .JoinAlias(() => Ma.MbList, () => Mb, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Where(() => Mb.ID == _MbId)
                .JoinAlias(() => Mb.McList, () => Mc,JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)                    
                    .Where(() => Mc.ID == _McId)
                .JoinAlias(() => Mc.MdList, () => Md, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Where(() => Md.ID == _MdID)                                             
                .OrderByAlias(() => Ma.ID).Asc
                .Take(iTake)
                .Skip(iSkip)
                .Future<ModelA>();
```

The previous code generate the follow SQL

```
SELECT TOP n Ma.*,Mb.*,Mc.*,Md.*
FROM Ma 
LEFT JOIN Mb ON (...conditions...)
LEFT JOIN Mc ON (...conditions...)
LEFT JOIN Md ON (...conditions...)
WHERE Mb.ID = _MbId
AND Mc.ID = _McId
AND Md.ID = _MdId
ORDER BY Ma.ID ASC
```

The problem is that Mc and Md table duplicates my result. So I would have only Ma and Mb in my SELECT statement.

```
SELECT TOP n Ma.*,Mb.*
FROM
.
.
.
```

How can I reach that result?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way is to use a pricipal QueryOver selecting the main model and a filtered SubQuery

I mean something like this

```
var qOverInclude = QueryOver.Of<MyModel>(() => mModel)
                .JoinAlias(() => mModel.MyList, () => mList, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Where(() => mList.ID == myID)
                    .And(() => mList.Type == myType)
                .Select(x => x.IdMyModel);

  var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<MyModel>(() => mModel)
                .JoinAlias(() => mModel.MyDescription, () => mDescription, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .Where(() => mDescription.IDLanguage == myLanguage)
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => mModel.IdMyModel).In(qOverSubQuery)
                .OrderByAlias(() => mModel.IdMyModel).Asc
                .Future<MyModel>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Fetch` instead of `JoinAlias`. Something like this should do the job:

```
... .QueryOver<Ma>().Fetch(ma => ma.MbList).Eager
```

and do **not** use `fetch="join"` in your mapping.

When you force NHibernate to use `join`, it will return as many rows as there are in the cartesian product of your tables. As you only need one list item per ModelA object, you have to let NHibernate use simple `select` statements instead of `join`.

Comment: Fetch mode allow me to "join" only ModelA to the other models, but I need to "join" ModelA to ModelB, ModelB to ModelC and ModelC to ModelD; how can I reach that resut or how can I use fetch mode with aliases? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to inform NHibernate to not repeat the root entity (ModelA). You can do this with the statement:

```
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```

Comment: I've tried this statement before posting but it don't works because I've a Take statement and the TrasformUsing is applied after the Take statement so I've less than nTake rows